# chain methods not executed within for loop

Tags: javascript, string, sorting

I am stuck with manipulating an array string in a for loop, i believe i didn't make any syntax mistakes but it still not working as expected:

```
var words = ['bac','ccc','cbd'];

for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
    words[i].split('').sort().join('');
 } //return ['bac','ccc','cbd'], which was expected to be words = ['abc', 'ccc','bcd'];
```

But it is working without looping through all the elements from `words` like:

```
words[0].split('').sort().join(''); // return 'abc'
```

So i am wondering why are those chain methods not working in a loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the assignment `words[i]=words[i].split('').sort().join('');`

```js
var words = ['bac','ccc','cbd'];

for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
    words[i]=words[i].split('').sort().join('');
    
 } // expected to be words = ['abc', 'ccc','bcd'];
console.log(words)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works. But could you tell me why is necessary to assign the value again to words[i], I thought each element( words[i] ) is already changed with the chain function

Comment: @JianNCI VanillaJS string functions does not do that by itself. We have to manually assign. it doesnt even work with single function, let alone chain function

Comment: @JianNCI as you said words[0].split('').sort().join(''); // return 'abc' it returns a value so you need to assign it to use it..

Answer (score 0):

You have to use assignment as VanillaJS string functions does not do assignment to the argument by itself or is passed as reference. It seem to be passed as value parameter.

```
var words = ['bac','ccc','cbd'];

for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
   words[i]= words[i].split('').sort().join('');
 } 
   console.log(words);
```

Checkout the screenshot below. It shows you that it does not work like you are expecting even without a loop.

[image]